# Are Bits Mathematical Term

Tags: bit

Bits are used to represent values in base 2, a bit can be either 1 or 0, representing 2 values.

Is this a mathematical term for representing units in base 2, or is it used strictly within the field of computer science?

Comment: BIT = BI(nary) (digi)T

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone can correct me here, but I have never seen bits referred to in any "standard" mathematical course, personally.

That is, with the exception of Discrete Mathematics, which for the sake of argument, I will consider strictly Computer Science and not both, since there is obviously quite a bit of overlap to the field of Mathematics from Computer Science.

To answer the question directly, I would say it is "strictly" a Computer Science term. That's not saying a non-Computer Science person wouldn't know what you're talking about necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

[By Merriam-Webster](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bit), it is down at the 4th definition:

> Definition of bit
>   **1**
>   :  a unit of computer information equivalent to the result of a choice between two alternatives (as yes or no, on or off)
>   **2**
>   :  the physical representation of a bit by an electrical pulse, a magnetized spot, or a hole whose presence or absence indicates data

---

Mathematics can still involve bits, but they are more known as [*Binary Numbers*](http://www.binarymath.info/).

The usage of bits is most widely used for computer science, so **most would consider *bits* as a computer science term**, while *binary numbers*, or *binary digits*, may be the term to use if you were looking for more math-oriented resources on the numbers themselves.

Answer (score -1):

bits are only either 1 or 0. The base 2 logarithms are called binary logarithms but not bits.